# Error ImportError: No module named 'np_plots'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the next code in python

```
import np_plots as npp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as m
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def plotLimitCycle(bval):
    rhs = lambda X, t: [-X[0]+X[1]*X[0]**2, bval - X[1]*X[0]**2]
    xeq, yeq = bval, 1.0/bval
    cyclerad = m.sqrt(1-bval)
    nbh = min(cyclerad, 0.05)
    IC = [xeq-nbh/5.0, yeq-nbh/5.0]
    time_span = np.linspace(0,400,40000)
    fig = plt.figure()
    solution = odeint(rhs, IC, time_span)
    X, Y = zip(*solution)
    plt.plot(X, Y)
    axes = plt.gca()
    axXmin, axXmax = axes.get_xlim()
    axYmin, axYmax = axes.get_ylim()
    xmin = max(-15, axXmin)
    xmax = min(15, axXmax)
    ymin = max(-15, axYmin)
    ymax = min(15, axYmax)
    X,Y,U,V = npp.ezDomainQuiver2D([[xmin, xmax],[ymin, ymax]],[25,25],lambda X: rhs(X, 0),Normalize=True)
    plt.quiver(X,Y,U,V)
    plt.scatter([xeq],[yeq], color='red')
    plt.xlim([xmin, xmax])
    plt.ylim([ymin, ymax])
    plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
    plt.show()
```

It work pretty well on my friend computer because he showed me the plots but I can't make it run in mine, I'm using Python 3.5.0cr1 Shell to run it out but it always came with te next error:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PankePünke\Desktop\limites.py", line 1, in <module>
    import np_plots as npp
ImportError: No module named 'np_plots'**
```

I'm totally new in Python programming and my friend made this program for me in order to make some advances in my thesis but I want to continue working with this program and get the plots from this. I do not know how to install or what kind of procceddure I should follow in order to get what I want (the plots and graphics that this program make) So... I'll be very thankful if somebody can help me in not a advance way, because how a wrote I'm totally new in Python, I just installed it and that is all.

Comment: This error means you don't have the python package np_plots in your computer. Surprisingly I didn't find it by googling either. Please ask your friend where this package is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You friend had a lib called `np_plots` on their computer, it is not part of the standard lib so you need to also install/get it on your comp or the code will not run. Most likely your friend actually wrote the code as I cannot see any mention of that lib  anywhere so you will have to get it from them.

Apart from your friends lib,  `scipy` and `numpy` are also not in the standard library, they do come with some distributions like Canopy but if you just installed a regular version of python you will need to install those also.

Might be worth checking out [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) as it is the de-facto standard package manager for python.

Comment: Sorry to bother all the people in here but, how can I install those libraries and my friend give the np_plots library so now where do I have to put them in order to run the program correctly.

Comment: Your friend gave you some .py files?

Comment: No my friend answwer some question that I've had and then put this link to show the simulations :

Comment: https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/6d1d7f14-0203-4836-8256-10282cc792b8/files/trapping_region.sagews

Comment: The I contacted him again in order to tell him that I can't run the program because I do not have the np_plot libraries and then he gave me this link:

https://gist.github.com/Evgenij-Gr/bcf24b826d830da06b65

so now I don't know where to put all thos libraries and commands and all of that in order to run the program correctly.

Comment: what os are you using? Anyway in relation to that file, download it, save it as `np_plots.py`,make sure you save it in the same folder as your script, run  the cscript and tell me how it goes